# How to avoid boilerplate code when type aggregates other types

Tags: f#

I'd like to model my domain.  I start with aggregation:

```
type Tree() =
  member x.Plant = ...
  member x.Trim = ...
  member x.Uproot = ...

type FruitTree(tree : Tree) =
  member x.Trim = ... // redefine
  member x.PickFruit = ...
  // and also make available members from Tree type without following boilerplate code to forward calls
  member x.Plant = tree.Plant
  member x.Uproot = tree.Uproot
```

How can I make members from the aggregated object available without having to spell them out?

EDIT

When inheriting, members of inherited type are in public surface of the newly created type. Is there a way to get similar effect with a container of aggregated types, without exposing the actual fields?

Comment: One way is to use inheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a couple of ways for doing this and it really depends on what you're actually doing - an example with trees and fruit trees is never going to be realistic enough for this. Have a look at [Scott Wlaschin's Domain Driven Design](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ddd/) materials, which are a great summary of the options.

In F#, people generally avoid inheritance and instead use composition. You could just write a wrapper that looks like this:

```
type FruitTree(tree : Tree) =
  member x.Tree = tree  // Expose the wrapped tree
  member x.PickFruit =  // Add other functionality here
```

This might work in some cases. If you're looking for a more functional solution, you should separate the data from the operations. Then you could define data structure that looks perhaps something like this:

```
type Tree = 
  | Ordinary of int     // Some data about tree - say, number of branches
  | Fruit of Tree * int // Annotates another tree with number of fruits
```

Then you can write functions for operating on trees:

```
let rec trim tree =
  match tree with
  | Ordinary(n) -> Ordinary(n-1) // Remove one branch from the tree
  | Fruit(t, f) -> Fruit(trim t, f) // Recursively apply on the wrapped tree
```

That said, you really need to give a more concrete example to get a useful answer..

Comment: When inheriting, members of inherited type are in public surface of the newly created type.  Is there a way to get similar effect with a container of aggregated types?  (of course I've seen the great DDD slide deck)

Comment: No, there is no way to make the members automatically visible on the composed type. It is quite hard to say what is the best approach in general - getting used to the functional-style of DDD takes some time! Perhaps if you describe a more specific minimal example...

Answer (score 1):

This question is asking for the core feature of inheritance. It *may* be a good solution to just use it. There is no fundamental issue with inheritance as long as

- the resulting types' features are *a perfect superset* of the base type's features, and
- it doesn't make the resulting code hard to reason about.

Inheritance is often discouraged because people use it where one of the above points does not hold. This results in messy types that expose members they shouldn't; these members then range from badly named to irrelevant or even invalid. This results in large, convoluted, unintuitive types, and it would often have been better to just ban inheritance from the whole project.

Composition also helps to cluster complexity; if a type is complicated, explicitly breaking it down into smaller parts can make reasoning about it easier.

But it is not the fault of inheritance features that sloppy programmers abuse them. In cases where the base class is not complex and the derived class should expose all base class features as-is, inheritance will make code succinct, consistent, and easier to maintain.

That said, there is currently no "middle way" between inheritance and composition with explicit forwarding of members. If inheritance exactly represents the given relation, use it; if not, any forwarding must be done manually. In either case, consider using the `internal` access modifier for members that should not leak into a library's API.